# Is there any provision available in GC to create user account when you spin up a linux instance

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

Is there any provision available in GC to create user account when you spin up a linux instance. I have tried Meta data and automation script in template creation .. but it does fit with my requirement. Aws provide this feature to a generic account when spin a instance using template and instance creation.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on what is your objective, and what you have tried with metadata and automation scripts that did or didn't fit with your requirements ? What are your requirements by the way ?

Comment: A default account will be created for you to login with straight away. If you want additional users, why aren't your scripts working? Also, consider if userify is a tool that'd be useful to you.